# Write jquery.ajax from existing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251073.aspx

How could I write 'get' request using jquery.ajax?

Comment: What is it you really want? Why do you need `get` requests? Moreover, don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent` to properly encode query parameters. They don't do that in the linked example.

Comment: -1 for linking to an article that doesn't clearly relate to the question, as well as for a question that isn't clear about what it is even asking. here's a shot in the dark to help you though: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Or just use the regular $.ajax() method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which defaults to a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether Bing's API respects the standard `?callback=function` method for specifying JSONP callbacks, but if so, then this simplified version of the `Search()` function should do it:

```
// Bing API 2.0 code sample demonstrating the use of the
// Spell SourceType over the JSON Protocol.
function Search()
{
        var requestStr = "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?"

        // Common request fields (required)
        + "AppId=" + AppId
        + "&Query=Mispeling words is a common ocurrence."
        + "&Sources=Spell"

        // Common request fields (optional)
        + "&Version=2.0"
        + "&Market=en-us"
        + "&Options=EnableHighlighting"

        $.getJSON(requestStr, SearchCompleted);
}
```

Keep in mind that neither approach is directly triggering a GET, like you might be used to in AJAX requests to a local server using XMLHttpRequest.

To circumvent the cross-domain restriction on XHR, JSONP works by injecting a new script element into your document which then causes the browser to load (via GET) and execute that remote script.  That remote script's contents are a single function call to your callback function, with the entire JSON payload as its parameter.

---

If that doesn't work, including those Bing-specific callback options should work fine in conjunction with jQuery:

```
// Bing API 2.0 code sample demonstrating the use of the
// Spell SourceType over the JSON Protocol.
function Search()
{
        var requestStr = "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?"

        // Common request fields (required)
        + "AppId=" + AppId
        + "&Query=Mispeling words is a common ocurrence."
        + "&Sources=Spell"

        // Common request fields (optional)
        + "&Version=2.0"
        + "&Market=en-us"
        + "&Options=EnableHighlighting"

        // JSON-specific request fields (optional)
        + "&JsonType=callback"
        + "&JsonCallback=SearchCompleted";

        $.getJSON(requestStr);
}
```

Keep in mind that, at this point (and somewhat before), you aren't really using jQuery itself for much at all.  Even though `$.getJSON()` or `$.ajax()` or `$.get()` seem like they're doing something more powerful than the MSDN example, jQuery is going to do exactly the same thing in this case (inject a script element with its `src`pointed at `requestStr`).

Comment: Callback function doesn't execute. I looked at this request in Fiddler and I saw staus:200 and response text.But I have no ideas how I can execute callback function. Could you help me?

Comment: Updated with another approach.